# Is there any way to mark ProgressBar OR SeekBar at some position with different color just like "Youtube" Ad marker?

Tags: android, progress-bar, seekbar

Actually I implemented custom video player in my app, also I'm showing video progress using SeekBar View. Now I want to show some marker just like "Youtube" Ad marker on my video progress bar, the number of markers and their respective position/index will be decide at runtime. I found this question ([How to mark horizontal ProgressBar with different color at some index just like Youtube video yellow color ad marker in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560247/how-to-mark-horizontal-progressbar-with-different-color-at-some-index-just-like)) asked before on stackoverflow, but unfortunately there is no solution yet. Please check below image to understand what exactly I want to achieve.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qxfsTu8WOPMIlek7616rVQgzab8CFVcp

Any help will be really very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check this other SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862585/horizontal-progressbar-add-circle-indicators it works at fixed distances but I'm sure you can adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @PKMBSD I know its quite late, but check my answer below which will surely help you to achieve what you want--

**Step-1]** Create one "attrs.xml" file in "res/values/" folder and paste below code in that file--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="DottedSeekBar">
        <attr name="dots_positions" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="dots_drawable" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Step-2]** Prepare one image icon which you want to use to mark on progress bar and name it "video_mark.png".

**Step-3]** Create one custom SeekBar as below--

```
public class DottedSeekBar extends AppCompatSeekBar {

    /** Int values which corresponds to dots */
    private int[] mDotsPositions = null;
    /** Drawable for dot */
    private Bitmap mDotBitmap = null;

    public DottedSeekBar(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public DottedSeekBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public DottedSeekBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes Seek bar extended attributes from xml
     *
     * @param attributeSet {@link AttributeSet}
     */
    private void init(final AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        final TypedArray attrsArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.DottedSeekBar, 0, 0);

        final int dotsArrayResource = attrsArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.DottedSeekBar_dots_positions, 0);

        if (0 != dotsArrayResource) {
            mDotsPositions = getResources().getIntArray(dotsArrayResource);
        }

        final int dotDrawableId = attrsArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.DottedSeekBar_dots_drawable, 0);

        if (0 != dotDrawableId) {
            mDotBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), dotDrawableId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param dots to be displayed on this SeekBar
     */
    public void setDots(final int[] dots) {
        mDotsPositions = dots;
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param dotsResource resource id to be used for dots drawing
     */
    public void setDotsDrawable(final int dotsResource)
    {
        mDotBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), dotsResource);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        final float width=getMeasuredWidth()-getPaddingLeft()-getPaddingRight();
        final float step=width/(float)(getMax());

        if (null != mDotsPositions && 0 != mDotsPositions.length && null != mDotBitmap) {
            // draw dots if we have ones
            for (int position : mDotsPositions) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mDotBitmap, position * step, 0, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step-4]** Use this custom SeekBar in your activity.xml file as below--

```
<com.your_package.DottedSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/videoProgress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Step-5]** Add below code in "onCreate()" method of your "Activity.java" class--

```
DottedSeekBar videoProgress = (DottedSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.videoProgress);
// Disable SeekBar Thumb Drag. (Optional)
        videoProgress.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });

// Set custom thumb icon here (Optional) 
  videoProgress.getThumb().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.cerulean_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

// Add below line to avoid unnecessary SeekBar padding. (Optional)
    videoProgress.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

// Handler to update video progress time--

```
handler = new Handler();
        // Define the code block to be executed
        final Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                updateCurrentTime();
                // Repeat this the same runnable code block again another 1 seconds
                // 'this' is referencing the Runnable object
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };

 yourVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                                      {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                                          {


                                              String strTotalDuration = msToTimeConverter(vidView.getDuration());

                                              String[] strTimeArr = strTotalDuration.split(":");

                                              int min = Integer.parseInt(strTimeArr[0]);
                                              int videoLengthInSec = Integer.parseInt(strTimeArr[1]);
                                              videoLengthInSec = videoLengthInSec + (min*60);

                                              videoProgress.setProgress(0);
                                              videoProgress.setMax(videoLengthInSec);

                                              // Start the initial runnable task by posting through the handler
                                              handler.post(runnableCode);

                                              initVideoMarkers();
                                          }
                                      }

        );
```

**Step-6]** Copy below required methods in your "Activity.java" class--

// Method to update time progress

```
private void updateCurrentTime()
    {
        if (videoProgress.getProgress() >= 100)
        {
            handler.removeMessages(0);
        }
        String currentPosition = msToTimeConverter(vidView.getCurrentPosition());

        String[] strArr = currentPosition.split(":");

        int progress = vidView.getCurrentPosition() * videoLengthInSec / vidView.getDuration();

        videoProgress.setProgress(progress);
    }
```

// Milliseconds to Time converter Method

```
 String msToTimeConverter(int millis)
    {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
    }
```

// Method to set Marker values

```
  private void initVideoMarkers()
        {
            videoProgress.setDots(new int[] {10, 15, 20});
            videoProgress.setDotsDrawable(R.drawable.video_mark);
       }
```

I had the same challenge and I'm using this solution, it works 100% fine. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.. Your solution is working perfect but I need to click the MARK on seekbar and play the video from that mark. Could you please help me on click event on Mark image ?